# Silverlight UserControl with rectangle as a button

Tags: silverlight, methods, user-controls

I have a problem using custom made UserControl in Silverlight Page.
The UserControl is generally a rectangle containing a smaller rectangle inside.
I want to use the UControl in a Silverlight MainSite.
i've implemented a method on mouse button down for a smaller rectangle called in here Button1:

```
public void Button1_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
     MessageBox.Show("Hello");
    }
```

How can i use it from a MainSite? From there I can only implement a method like:

```
private void ImportedControl_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        firstLeaf.Button1_MouseLeftButtonDown(sender, e);
    }
```

I can not implement a method for Button1.

How can i mek this Work?
HELP:)

Comment: I really don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: I made a user control where I put a rectangle. The rectangle is called Button1, and serves as a button. using this control in a project I can not refer to an object Button1 or klick options.

Comment: I would add that the control was done in Expression Blend tool, but it still does not matter

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure I understand the question, but let me take a swing at an answer.  Why don't you use a real Button and just template it with a rectangle?  This way you get all the benefits of actually having a button while having it look like a rectangle, including the Click event.

Here is a post Scott Guthrie did on [control templating with a button](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/silverlight-tutorial-part-7-using-control-templates-to-customize-a-control-s-look-and-feel.aspx).